# Give a confirmation alert before closing Chrome custom tab in Android

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I have an issue with Chrome custom tab. Whenever the user presses the back button on the toolbar, Chrome custom tab gives no confirmation alert before it closes itself. I want to track the event which handles the pressing of back-button. Instead, it directly closes the window.